# How to pass predicate correctly in the closure in this case?

Tags: swift

While passing predicate in the closure in the generic function, I get follwoing errors. How can I solve this.

```
func find <T: IteratorProtocol> (generator : T, predicate: (T.Element) -> Bool) -> T.Element? {
var gen = generator
while let x = gen.next() {
    if predicate(x) {
        return x
    }
  }
  return nil
}

var nums:[Int] = [2,3,5,6]
```

**Error:** cannot convert value of type '(Int) -> Bool' to expected argument type '(_) -> Bool'

```
let get = find(generator: nums){ (x:Int) -> Bool in
   return x <= 4
}
```

If I change the closure as follow, the **error** is 
 ambiguous use of operator '<='

```
let get = find(generator: nums)  {
    $0 <= 4
}
```

If I cast the value to Int, **error:** generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred.

```
let get = find(generator: nums)  {
    let b = $0 as Int
    return b <= 4
}
```

Comment: Please show `nums` declaration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `find` function takes an *iterator* as an argument, not a *sequence.* An array
conforms to `Sequence` but not to `IteratorType`. So your predicates 
are correct, but you have to pass the sequences iterator as the first
argument:

```
let get = find(generator: nums.makeIterator()) { (x:Int) -> Bool in
    return x <= 4
}
```

or

```
let get = find(generator: nums.makeIterator())  {
    $0 <= 4
}
```

or change your function to take a `Sequence` argument.

But note that you achieve the same result with the existing 
`first(where:)` method introduced in Swift 3:

```
if let y = nums.first(where: { $0 <= 4 } ) {
    print(y)
}
```